# Module Page Keeps Redirecting

Tags: 7

I inherited someone else's project.

I see he created a module called `bcompanies.module`.  In that module file I see this:

```
function bcompanies_menu() {
    $items['company'] = array(
        'title'     => 'Company',
        'page arguments'    => array(1),
        'page callback' => 'company_page',
        'access callback'   => TRUE,
        'type'          => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
    $items['company_page2'] = array(
        'title'     => 'Company',
        'page arguments'    => array(1),
        'page callback' => 'company_page',
        'access callback'   => TRUE,
        'type'          => MENU_CALLBACK
    );

}

function company_page()
{
      return 'hello world';
}
```

When I go to the url `http://site.com/company`, I see the text "hello world".  When I go to the url `http://site.com/company_page2`, I am redirected to `http://site.com/welcome` .   Does anyone know why the second url keeps redirecting me while the first does not, even though they seems exactly the same in terms of set up?

I did a test and wrote a die() statement in company_page(), that forced it to not redirect.   But that's not that great, because it prevents subsequent drupal hooks from firing.

**Additional Notes**

I noticed that if I login as an admin user, then there is NO REDIRECT when i go to `http://site.com/company_page2` - I see hello world wrapped nicely by the header html template and the footer html template.  The redirect only happens when i login as a regular user going to that page.

So is this a permission/role issue?  But I never set the permission or role or anything...

Comment: Does your site have anything like the Path Access module (https://drupal.org/project/path_access) installed?

Answer (score 0):

There can not be a permission issue in your code (because you code is very simple:) ). Just try to change your code as documentation says:

```
function bcompanies_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['company'] = array(
        'title'     => 'Company',
        'page arguments'    => array(), // I removed arguments because of callback function doesn't require in your case;
        'page callback' => 'company_page',
        'access callback'   => 'user_access', // I changed your access callback, it's a bad practice to set just TRUE as an access callback
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type'          => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
    $items['company_page2'] = array(
        'title'     => 'Company',
        'page arguments'    => array(),
        'page callback' => 'company_page',
        'access callback'   => 'user_access',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type'          => MENU_CALLBACK
    );

    return $items; // I added this line, because I don't know you 're returning a value in your module or not..

}

function company_page()
{
      return 'hello world';
}
```